# LINQ query to get the right data

Tags: c#, linq

I had a quick question about how to do this in a LINQ query. I'm having problems performing it mainly because I'm still learning LINQ and I was hoping you guys could point me in the right direction.

Basically I have a table like below

```
Number Character Key
1      a         value & 2
1      a         value & 2
1      b         value & 1
2      a         value & 3
3      b         value & 4
3      a         value & 5
4      a         value & 7
4      a         value & 7
4      b         value & 8
4      b         value & 9
```

I want to write a LINQ query that first groups by the number column, then within that result, again groups by the character column and then checks to see within that result if the value in the key column matches between the two.

I hope my language isn't confusing.

Thank you

Edit:

I'm using a list that was generated from an excel file.

```
            List<Data> bdt = getData.dataGet(exp);
            var result = from s in bdt
```

The output I would want is

```
Number Character Key
1      a         value & 2
1      a         value & 2
4      a         value & 7
4      a         value & 7
```

Thanks for the suggestions, I'll keep them in mind for next time

Comment: Please don't include an image when just putting the text into the question would make it easier for everyone to read...

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this so I didn't know how to properly format a table. I apolagize

Comment: What table class are you using, and what output do you want? (An example would be nice..)

Comment: so you want to identify the duplicates, right?

Comment: @Serge - appTranslator Yes Serge, but it's duplicates across the numbers, characters and keys.  I tried to do it by using groupbys, but I think I'm making a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
var q =
    from item in bdt
    group item by new { item.Number, item.Character, item.Key } into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Key;
```

The trick is to a single `group by` on multiple columns :-)

Comment: Thank you for you'r help. Appreciate the answer

Comment: @Predeep: If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as answer :-)